# Stored Procedure Scope of transcation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a bunch of transactions in a stored procedure which fails from time to time because either the table doesn't exist or column does exist.

So for example

```
If object_id ('test.dbo.test') is not null 
    drop table test

select *
into test   
from testdata

If object_id ('test.dbo.test2') is not null 
    drop table test2

select *
into test2
from testdata2
```

I am thinking of using go to end the batch for each part but will that end stored procedure from the first instance of the word go.

Will a semicolon suffice at all or would something like a begin and end to be used for this?

Comment: using a `BEGIN` and `END` for each if statement should suffice, hard to tell with the limited info given here

Comment: Hi, What I'm basically doing is creating table, updating table and then dropping table. I have a host of these scripts as part of one stored proc. But time to time then etl process fails despite having a go and I tried a semi colon. But because I have a over dozens of transaction considering I have  create, update and then drop etc for each part of followed by the same process again with another table.